# jQuery: scaleY and scaleX at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to Flip and Flop an image/div on click of buttons.

I use the `scaleX and scaleY` properties and it works but not the way I want.

basically when I click on the Flip or Flop, the scaleX or scaleY positions will be lost. which means it will only apply 1 of them to the div at a time.

**here is a jsfiddle in action:**

http://jsfiddle.net/6hzwyyjk/

click on flip or flop (doesn't matter) and then click on the other button and you will see that the first button action is lost.

this is my code:

```
$('#flip').click(function(e){
    //$("#droppable .selected img").addClass('drag2');

      $("#myDiv").css({
            "transform": "scaleY(-1)",
            "-moz-transform": "scaleY(-1)",
            "-o-transform": "scaleY(-1)",
            "-webkit-transform": "scaleY(-1)",
            "filter": "FlipV",
            "-ms-filter": "FlipV"
        }
);
});

$('#flop').click(function(e){
    //$("#droppable .selected img").addClass('drag3');
      $("#myDiv").css({

            "transform": "scaleX(-1)",
            "-moz-transform": "scaleX(-1)",
            "-o-transform": "scaleX(-1)",
            "-webkit-transform": "scaleX(-1)",
            "filter": "FlipH",
            "-ms-filter": "FlipH"

        }
);  

});
```

Comment: `"transform": "scaleX(-1) " + $("#myDiv").css('transform')` and so on

Comment: not sure what that is @Alex

Comment: working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hzwyyjk/1/

Comment: I would handle the transforms with css:


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/6hzwyyjk/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var i=-1,j=-1;
$('#flip').click(function(e){
    //$("#droppable .selected img").addClass('drag2');

      $("#myDiv").css({
            "transform": "scaleY("+i+")",
            "-moz-transform": "scaleY("+i+")",
            "-o-transform": "scaleY("+i+")",
            "-webkit-transform": "scaleY("+i+")",
            "filter": "FlipV",
            "-ms-filter": "FlipV"
        }
);
           i=-i;

});

$('#flop').click(function(e){
    //$("#droppable .selected img").addClass('drag3');
      $("#myDiv").css({

            "transform": "scaleX("+j+")",
            "-moz-transform": "scaleX("+j+")",
            "-o-transform": "scaleX("+j+")",
            "-webkit-transform": "scaleX("+j+")",
            "filter": "FlipH",
            "-ms-filter": "FlipH"

        }
);  
    j=-j;

});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hzwyyjk/5/)**

Comment: When I run your own Fiddle, it loses the current image state on click. So the image performs the flip or flop based on the original image rather than the previous state (after two clicks).